# CMake tesseract error: "file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch" | ocrmypdf

Tags: python, cmake, tesseract

system: Windows 7 pro

I am trying to run ocrmypdf in python, but I am receiving error:

```
    raise MissingDependencyError(
ocrmypdf.exceptions.MissingDependencyError: 
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        This error normally occurs when ocrmypdf can't find the Leptonica
        library, which is usually installed with Tesseract OCR. It could be that
        Tesseract is not installed properly, we can't find the installation
        on your system PATH environment variable.

        The library we are looking for is usually called:
            liblept-5.dll   (Windows)
            liblept*.dylib  (macOS)
            liblept*.so     (Linux/BSD)

        Please review our installation procedures to find a solution:
            https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

I've decided to install `tesseract` , to do that i need to build files from this library. I am using Cmake to do that, already build Leptonica and TiFF for Tesseract.

But when I am trying to "configure" tesseract in Cmake I am receiving this error:

```
 CMake Error at training/CMakeLists.txt:40 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [tesseract-3.05.01/build_win64/training/icu/icu64.zip]
      expected hash: [480c72491576c048de]
        actual hash: [db340097e390be978d]
             status: [0;"No error"]
```

I 've also changed in `tesseract\training\CMakeLists.txt` this line:

`"http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/56.1/icu4c-56_1-Win${ARCH_DIR_NAME}-msvc10.zip"` to : `https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-68-2/icu4c-68_2-Win64-MSVC2019.zip` because there was a problem with this zip file.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be important for someone in future:

to solve this problem, you dont need to compile those libraries on your own, I've found `liblept-5.dll` when I installed tesseract from here:

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

using latest installers